# Not apply values on ajax call in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces dialog on which I have a group of Radio Button and two text fields.I want to enable/disable these text fields on the `change` event of radio buttons.
Here is my code of dialog box

```
<h:panelGrid  style="float:left;">
                            <h:selectOneRadio id="timeLimit" layout="pageDirection" value="#{bean.selectedOption}" onchange="submit()"
                            valueChangeListener="#{bean.enableDisableDecision}">
                            <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="from to"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Once Only"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="From:"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Permanent"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="Ignore"/>
                            </h:selectOneRadio>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText id="c" value="#{renderBean.limitFields}"/>

                            <h:inputText id="from" disabled="#{renderBean.limitFields}"></h:inputText>

                            <h:outputText style="margin-left:-20px;float:left;margin-top: 20px;" value="To: "/>
                            <h:inputText id="to" style="float:left; margin-top: -20px;" disabled="#{renderBean.limitFields}"></h:inputText>
```

And Here is my RenderBean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RenderBean {
    public boolean limitFields;

    public RenderBean() {

        limitFields = true;
    }

    public boolean isLimitFields() {
        return limitFields;
    }

    public void setLimitFields(boolean limitFields) {
        this.limitFields = limitFields;
    }

    public void enableLimitFields() {

        limitFields = false;
    }

    public void disableLimitFields() {

        limitFields = true;
    }
}
```

AND here is my Bean class in which I am invoking the listener.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScope
class Bean{
public void durationSelected(ValueChangeEvent e){

        RenderBean rb = null;
        System.out.println("Value: "+e.getNewValue().toString());
        if(e.getNewValue().toString().equals("2")){
            rb = (RenderBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("renderBean");
            rb.enableLimitFields();
        }else{
             rb = (RenderBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("renderBean");
             rb.disableLimitFields();
        }
    }
}
```

Now my code is working perfect and it is invoking the methods without any problem but it doesn't enable/disable text fields when I change the selection of Radio button.It means values are changing but they are not read by JSF component on ajax call.Now I am stuck here.Any syggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `onchange="submit()"` from your radio button.I am not JSF expert but I guess when you are sending ajax request then just execute the data from your `<f:ajax ..` and then no need to submit it.So when I copy paste your example , It was not working and then I tried it by removing `onchange="submit"` , It worked fine :)